# How to get GSF (Google Service Framework) ID from adb?

Tags: java, android, adb

I found out it could be done in java through

```
Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.gsf.gservices");
```

and many app on play store could do that. However, is there anyway the gsf id can be obtained through adb?

I tried:

```
content query --uri content://settings/secure/android_id #to get the android id
content query --uri content://settings/secure/ #to see the list of dictionaries but gsf id not in there
content query --uri content://com.google.android.gsf.gservice #doesn't return a value, and this should be where the java code in the app get the value from, already granted superuser for the shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ adb root


$ adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db "select * from main where name = \"android_id\";"'
```

this might help,
Connect the phone to your PC, with the USB Debugger enabled. Then open powershell or cmd at adb folder in PC and enter the commands provided..

Comment: How might it help? Your answer isn't very helpful without any explanation of what you're doing and why it will solve the problem. Also, please put your code in a code block

Comment: Note that you need `sqlite3` binary for this answer. You can get it e.g. from by installing [termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) and then execute `pkg install sqlite`. Then you will find sqlite3 binary in `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sqlite3`.